# SQL Query That Requires 4 Tables For the Solution V2

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need some help solving this query for my project. The query I'm working on requires 4 tables.

These are the tables:

```
Create Table course (code char(11) Primary Key,
                name varchar(30),
                points int,
                check (points >= 1 and points <= 12));

Create Table student (id char(7) Primary Key,
                     first_name varchar(12),
                     surname varchar(30),
                     bsn char(11), 
                     start_date date
                     );

Create Table aregiven (studentid char(7) References student(id),
                  coursecode char(11),
                  assignmentcode char(13),
                  Primary Key (studentid, coursecode, assignmentcode),
                  Foreign Key (coursecode, assignmentcode) References 
                  assignment(coursecode, assignmentcode));

Create Table has_completed (studentid char(7) References student(id),
                        studyprogram_level varchar(10),
                        studyprogram_name varchar(15),
                        Primary Key (studentid, studyprogram_name, studyprogram_level)
                        );
```

I need to find the students(first_name & surname) that have completed their studies and sum all the points of the courses that the student followed. 
I thought that the best way to do this was to use a subquery to filter all of the students that completed their study program and than sum all of the points for each student.

This is what I was thinking of:

```
Select s.first_name, s.surname, SUM(c.points)
from course c, aregiven a, (Select * from student, has_completed
    where student.id = has_completed.studentid) as s
where c.code = a.coursecode and a.studentid = s.id
group by s.first_name, s.surname;
```

The only problem with this query is the fact that not all students are given assignments. So this means some students that have completed their study program won't be in the list.

I'm kinda stuck so I would really appreciate some help.

Oh yeah , this is the data I'm working with:

```
    Insert Into student Values
   ('0817347', 'Adelaide', 'Kemp', '55540-32016', '2012-02-29'),
   ('0889300', 'Addison', 'Lewis', '62874-60266', '2012-11-14'),
   ('0838756', 'Chandler', 'Mcgowan', '31573-29574', '2011-10-07'),
   ('0832660', 'Averi', 'Horn', '57137-29593', '2013-01-28'),
   ('0820356', 'Paola', 'Montoya', '92971-17968', '2010-11-29'),
   ('0874162', 'Joslyn', 'Mann', '28097-88031', '2011-10-17'),
   ('0855759', 'Mckenna', 'Hodge', '10062-01495', '2011-06-03'),
   ('0861973', 'Ayanna', 'Everett', '72133-12008', '2013-01-07'),
   ('0891964', 'Ruby', 'Snow', '29773-16346', '2011-12-18'),
   ('0827171', 'Arya', 'Campos', '18120-95884', '2013-01-21'),
   ('0886733', 'Yaretzi', 'Joseph', '88344-15559', '2010-10-21'),
   ('0885275', 'Leah', 'Roman', '89744-83342', '2010-01-03'),
   ('0837712', 'Corinne', 'Huffman', '66587-05136', '2011-04-03'),
   ('0803756', 'Enrique', 'Tyson', '41401-89947', '2012-12-30'),
   ('0832106', 'Holly', 'Kinney', '96961-48255', '2011-11-04'),
   ('0871899', 'Jaxton', 'Huffman', '58680-81239', '2010-12-24'),
   ('0834667', 'Leland', 'Mullen', '49088-99950', '2013-08-23'),
   ('0848042', 'Quincy', 'Merritt', '13619-35297', '2010-11-07'),
   ('0882325', 'Zara', 'Alford', '40831-15016', '2010-10-15'),
   ('0891031', 'Samantha', 'Jackson', '24874-47775', '2012-09-13'),
   ('0846211', 'Jaxen', 'James', '98978-28953', '2012-11-13'),
   ('0853161', 'Jonas', 'Rivas', '47853-96551', '2012-03-10'),
   ('0819175', 'Jaidyn', 'Clemons', '76470-06519', '2012-08-27'),
   ('0839441', 'Ayleen', 'Lee', '29551-94776', '2010-12-19'),
   ('0857631', 'Gauge', 'Stewart', '98473-70192', '2011-11-23'),
   ('0857382', 'Bruce', 'Carey', '70786-61873', '2010-01-01'),
   ('0816380', 'Amani', 'Love', '25672-23781', '2010-12-09'),
   ('0808692', 'Taraji', 'Mills', '80141-75446', '2012-02-03'),
   ('0875869', 'Keira', 'Byrd', '33465-41147', '2013-03-27'),
   ('0800811', 'Deegan', 'Strong', '57118-37389', '2011-07-05'),
   ('0838774', 'Marvin', 'Mcmahon', '39361-84625', '2010-09-14'),
   ('0848415', 'Lindsay', 'Walker', '90980-43462', '2011-06-28'),
   ('0840712', 'Alden', 'Ware', '11362-49381', '2013-03-19'),
   ('0889517', 'Heaven', 'Brady', '04490-83342', '2010-05-13'),
   ('0804162', 'Arabella', 'Villarreal', '19814-98358', '2011-02-26'),
   ('0870247', 'Stephen', 'Roy', '74814-12661', '2011-10-11'),
   ('0823855', 'Lukas', 'Ortega', '53365-11487', '2010-10-14'),
   ('0885385', 'Rylie', 'Gill', '59235-16274', '2013-01-21'),
   ('0852696', 'Keira', 'Owens', '40390-46701', '2011-04-29'),
   ('0882301', 'Steven', 'Thompson', '50374-80378', '2012-09-15'),
   ('0835161', 'Shelby', 'Buck', '71238-52210', '2011-04-14'),
   ('0822564', 'Collin', 'Santos', '53223-20765', '2012-01-06'),
   ('0821986', 'Zain', 'Nelson', '36805-56788', '2013-10-28'),
   ('0812982', 'Juliana', 'Ewing', '40267-88898', '2010-11-14'),
   ('0843262', 'Madison', 'Malone', '39761-44632', '2013-11-25'),
   ('0805577', 'Aria', 'Serrano', '90238-09850', '2010-03-24'),
   ('0845288', 'Willa', 'Vance', '02587-13960', '2013-03-23'),
   ('0859163', 'Nathanael', 'Hood', '63909-93284', '2013-08-06'),
   ('0810022', 'Jaidyn', 'Bond', '99102-95164', '2012-03-03'),
   ('0857370', 'Milo', 'Pollard', '80725-49081', '2010-10-12');


Insert Into course Values
   ('CRS01', 'Programming Basics', '3'),
   ('CRS02', 'OO Programming', '2'),
   ('CRS03', 'Database Design', '3'),
   ('CRS04', 'Software Testing', '3'),
   ('CRS05', 'Modelling', '3'),
   ('CRS06', 'Web Programming', '3'),
   ('CRS07', 'Requirement Engineering', '4'),
   ('CRS08', 'Operating Systems', '2'),
   ('CRS09', 'Hardware Design', '3'),
   ('PRJ01', 'Game Development', '4'),
   ('PRJ02', 'Data Analysis Applications', '4'),
   ('PRJ03', 'Simulators', '2'),
   ('PRJ04', 'Mobile Apps', '3'),
   ('PRJ05', 'Parallel Programming', '3'),
   ('PRJ06', 'Advanced Technologies', '3');


Insert Into has_completed Values
   ('0871899', 'BSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0834667', 'BSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0848042', 'BSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0882325', 'BSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0891031', 'BSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0846211', 'MSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0819175', 'MSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0839441', 'MSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0857631', 'MSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0857382', 'MSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0816380', 'MSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0808692', 'MSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0875869', 'MSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0800811', 'BSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0838774', 'BSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0848415', 'BSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0840712', 'MSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0889517', 'MSC', 'Informatica'),
   ('0804162', 'MSC', 'Informatica');

Insert Into aregiven Values
   ('0817347', 'CRS01', 'HMW54'),
   ('0817347', 'CRS01', 'HMW44'),
   ('0817347', 'CRS01', 'HMW41'),
   ('0817347', 'CRS01', 'HMW37'),
   ('0820356', 'CRS05', 'HMW03'),
   ('0820356', 'CRS05', 'HMW66'),
   ('0820356', 'CRS05', 'HMW99'),
   ('0820356', 'CRS05', 'HMW39'),
   ('0827171', 'PRJ01', 'HMW04'),
   ('0827171', 'PRJ01', 'HMW23'),
   ('0827171', 'PRJ01', 'HMW59'),
   ('0886733', 'PRJ02', 'HMW59'),
   ('0837712', 'PRJ04', 'HMW55'),
   ('0837712', 'PRJ04', 'HMW78'),
   ('0837712', 'PRJ04', 'HMW77'),
   ('0837712', 'PRJ04', 'HMW16'),
   ('0837712', 'PRJ04', 'HMW62'),
   ('0837712', 'PRJ04', 'HMW13'),
   ('0837712', 'PRJ04', 'HMW34'),
   ('0837712', 'PRJ04', 'HMW74'),
   ('0871899', 'CRS01', 'HMW54'),
   ('0871899', 'CRS01', 'HMW44'),
   ('0871899', 'CRS01', 'HMW41'),
   ('0871899', 'CRS01', 'HMW37'),
   ('0891031', 'CRS05', 'HMW03'),
   ('0891031', 'CRS05', 'HMW66'),
   ('0891031', 'CRS05', 'HMW99'),
   ('0891031', 'CRS05', 'HMW39'),
   ('0857631', 'PRJ01', 'HMW04'),
   ('0857631', 'PRJ01', 'HMW23'),
   ('0857631', 'PRJ01', 'HMW59'),
   ('0857382', 'PRJ02', 'HMW59'),
   ('0808692', 'PRJ04', 'HMW55'),
   ('0808692', 'PRJ04', 'HMW78'),
   ('0808692', 'PRJ04', 'HMW77'),
   ('0808692', 'PRJ04', 'HMW16'),
   ('0808692', 'PRJ04', 'HMW62'),
   ('0808692', 'PRJ04', 'HMW13'),
   ('0808692', 'PRJ04', 'HMW34'),
   ('0808692', 'PRJ04', 'HMW74'),
   ('0838774', 'CRS01', 'HMW54'),
   ('0838774', 'CRS01', 'HMW44'),
   ('0838774', 'CRS01', 'HMW41'),
   ('0838774', 'CRS01', 'HMW37'),
   ('0804162', 'CRS05', 'HMW03'),
   ('0804162', 'CRS05', 'HMW66'),
   ('0804162', 'CRS05', 'HMW99'),
   ('0804162', 'CRS05', 'HMW39'),
   ('0882301', 'PRJ01', 'HMW04'),
   ('0882301', 'PRJ01', 'HMW23'),
   ('0882301', 'PRJ01', 'HMW59'),
   ('0835161', 'PRJ02', 'HMW59'),
   ('0821986', 'PRJ04', 'HMW55'),
   ('0821986', 'PRJ04', 'HMW78'),
   ('0821986', 'PRJ04', 'HMW77'),
   ('0821986', 'PRJ04', 'HMW16'),
   ('0821986', 'PRJ04', 'HMW62'),
   ('0821986', 'PRJ04', 'HMW13'),
   ('0821986', 'PRJ04', 'HMW34'),
   ('0821986', 'PRJ04', 'HMW74'),
   ('0805577', 'CRS01', 'HMW54'),
   ('0805577', 'CRS01', 'HMW44'),
   ('0805577', 'CRS01', 'HMW41'),
   ('0805577', 'CRS01', 'HMW37'),
   ('0857370', 'CRS05', 'HMW03'),
   ('0857370', 'CRS05', 'HMW66'),
   ('0857370', 'CRS05', 'HMW99'),
   ('0857370', 'CRS05', 'HMW39');
```

Comment: Where is stored who completed which course? `has_completed` has no reference to `course` as far as I can see? Is that information retrievable otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not getting any results because you're using `JOIN` where you need to use a `LEFT JOIN`, which will still return results even with no matching rows in the joined table.

Try this query (it's MySQL but I think should work on PostgreSQL):

```
Select s.first_name, s.surname, SUM(c.points)
from student s
join has_completed h 
on h.studentid = s.id
left join aregiven a
on a.studentid = s.id
left join course c
on c.code = a.coursecode
group by s.first_name, s.surname;
```

Note you should probably group by `s.id` in case you have two students with the same name.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! thanks for the help @Nick

Comment: Great. Glad to be of help.